# Injury/Danger from uneven muscles?

Tags: weightlifting

I recently had a [question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/39320/activate-lats-evenly?noredirect=1#comment60866_39320) about my uneven lats on here. Since the lats are responsable for scapula-movements to a degree, can uneven lats (and/or traps maybe) be dangerous when performing movements like bench press in which scapula retraction is key for shoulder safety? Or is the difference to small to be dangerous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that outer size appearance will not have too much of an affect. But I do know from past training mistakes that if one side is significantly weaker strength wise then you should do some isolation exercises to try strengthen it. Otherwise it can lead to your body compensating in the wrong way and can lead to an injury.

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing unilateral isolation work in order to get rid of the imbalance now since i noticed it. But I was wondering if the imbalance itself might lead to a higher risk of injury in other exercises until I've gotten rid of it.

Comment: If you are working on it already and the difference in the imbalance is minor then I would say there is a small chance of becoming injured due to this. Unless you are lifting extremely heavy in your other exercises. But rather sacrifice weight over form. @Suimon

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have one side which is massively and noticeably bigger in size than the other... you'll not encounter any danger from the difference in uneven lats.

If it doesn't feel comfortable find another way. If you can't feel it then likelihood is that it won't be affecting you.